# Windows Scheduler - Script Execution Error

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to set up Windows Task Scheduler to run the upload_xml.cmd script below:

Inside this script I call several other files that have FTP commands, but when I run the task scheduler I configured, it only runs until step 2. How can I solve this problem?

```
:Step 1
Echo step 1 - Check for xml files to process
Netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off
Of xmls.list /f/q
Dir /s/b C:\xml\UPLOAD\*.xml xmls.list
Find /c ".xml xmls.list
If% errorlevel% equ 1 goto Exit
Echo step 1 - Files found
: Step2
Echo step 2 - run the ftp script to check if the connection exists
In10xml_connect /f/q
Ftp -s: download_connect.ftpget xx.xxx.xxx.xx
If not exist in10xml_connect goto Exit
Echo step 2 - SUCCESSFUL CONNECTION
: Step3
Echo step 3 - run the ftp script to check if you can send the files
In10xml_loader.lock /f/q
Ftp -s: download_lock.ftpget xx.xxx.xxx.xx
If exist in10xml_loader.lock goto Exit
Echo step 3 - UPLOAD CAN CONTINUE
```

Comment: Did you test the script running it from the command prompt?

Comment: Yes. It just does not work when I try to run the script through windows task scheduler.

Comment: So it works when executed directly from command promp, but fails as an scheduled task? is that correct?